# Xamarin Forms, Metadata Error - app used to Build just fine

Tags: xamarin, meta

My first question on the site.

I just came back to my project after 2 days, and have tried out flutter. 
My app used to run fine on android, now it gives me a metadata error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0006  Metadata file
>   'C:\Users\frede\source\repos\GoogleCalendarStatistics\GoogleCalendarStatistics\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\ref\GoogleCalendarStatistics.dll'
>   could not be
>   found GoogleCalendarStatistics.Android    C:\Users\frede\source\repos\GoogleCalendarStatistics\GoogleCalendarStatistics.Android\CSC   1   Active

Comment: Try to delete bin and obj folder and rebuild , refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99983/can-not-build-anymore-error-cs0006-metadata-file-could-not-be-found .

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you, Cole Xia.

Comment: Sure go ahead :)

Answer (score 2):

It may do the trick that delete bin and obj folder and rebuild .

Details refer https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/99983/can-not-build-anymore-error-cs0006-metadata-file-could-not-be-found.

Comment: Just click the √ button on left side .

Comment: Could you accept the answer to help that people who faces the same problem ?